# ID for Off-Brand 1x1 Round Plate, Stud on BOTH Sides (1 is Hollow)

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I have a round 1x1 plate (from a blind by-the-pound secondhand sale) with a male stud on both sides of the plate, no female holes. One stud is hollow, the other is solid with a large "C" and a smaller "3" next to it, similar to a cubed notation (superscript). I think it might be C3, (Create, Construct, Customize), but I don't know how to find individual parts for that brand.

So what is it from, and how can I get more? These things are amazing for inverting directions!
[image: Top w/Lego comparison on left]
[image: Bottom with Lego comparison on left]
[image: Side view with Lego for comparison on left]

Comment: Looks like the brand is defunct: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimates

Comment: I see that the figure sets are still continued, under a different license, but I don't see part lists for them (no do I see actual sets anymore, just the figures).  Thanks for the confirmation on the brand though!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know this exact brand, but please note that Mega Bloks (now Mega Construx) has those male/male studs. They appear in many of their sets and come in many different colors. They are exactly one plate tall, just like the one you have on your picture. The Mega version has a hole going through the middle to accommodate any bar shaped piece, which makes them even more useful!

Comment: Do you happen to know what the part number for the 1x1 double male plates in MC is?  I found a site that shows cropped tiny pictures of some pieces with numbers, but it's hard to tell (https://s219.photobucket.com/user/Orrex/library/Parts?page=1).

I see they have several others, like a 1x2 and 2x2 plates, as well as bricks and brackets and hinges, oh my.  I'll have to buy the sets themselves since MC doesn't do individual pieces, but I really wish I could track down these 1x1 round m-m plates; making a custom minifig for my son, and it's essential to get more!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Eric, it's tough because Mega's part numbers are unique to both the part shape and color. For example, in the #FVG41 Destiny set, the part appears In pearl-gold, and the part number is AM76558ATH. I believe the last three letters refer to the color, and the numbers and letters before the last three letters refer to the part design.